# How do I get 1 record as result including a left join including a loop?

Tags: sql-server, loops, left-join, data-warehouse

I have a situation that I cannot figure out on my own and would like to have support in it how to solve it:
I’m currently building a data warehouse on SQL server 18. In the staging db I have a SoLine table that combines the data from several Oracle tables. Among those tables is ONT.OE_Order_Price_Attribs which contains de Header_Id and Line_Id to join on the base table ONT.OE_Order_Lines_All:

```
SELECT
    OL.*,
    OPA.*
FROM ONT.OE_Order_Lines_All OL

LEFT JOIN ONT.OE_Order_Price_Attribs OPA
    ON OL.Header_Id = OPA.Header_Id
    AND OL.Line_Id = OPA.Line_Id
```

OPA contains sometimes multiple records per Header_Id, Line_Id and Last_Update_Date (so those contain all the same values):

| Header_Id | Line_Id | Last_Update_Date | Pricing_Context | Order_Price_Attrib_Id | Att1 | Att2 | Att3 | Att4 | Att5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | 2023-12-13 10:00:00 | 01 | 789 | A | B | C | D | *E* |
| 123 | 456 | 2023-12-13 10:00:00 | 01 | 790 | A | B | C | D | *F* |

The rest of the columns are also identical except for column Order_Price_Attrib_Id. It can occur that the att* columns are the same or different though.

What I want to achieve is that I have only 1 record as result. In case when the columns Header_Id, Line_Id and Last_Update_Date are the same, it should show the record with the latest Order_price_Attrib_Id. So in the above example Id 790, despite if the att* are the same or different. But I do want to see the att* columns

So for each Header_Id and Line_Id combination from the order line table, it needs to find the latest Header_Id and Line_id of the attrib tables based on the Order_Price_Attrib_Id for each record in the SoLine table.
So a loop is (at least I think) needed to find each combination.

I have tried to use the MAX function on Order_Price_Attrib_Id but that didn’t work out unfortunately. I also tried to use a sub-query with a count(*) and such. But no results unfortunatly so far.

I have a hard time to write these more advanced/difficult queries since I’m not a real expert in writing queries. I can write the basics but these type of queries are a bit out of reach yet at the moment.

So any help is highly appreciated and therefore already thank you in advance.

Yoeri

I don't seem to get in any way to only have 1 record as a result per record in the SoLine table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a unique sequential number to each row within defined groups, specified by `PARTITION BY` clause, then we select the latest row per group, by using `ORDER BY` clause to sort the data in descending order :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    OL.*,
    OPA.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OL.Header_Id, OL.Line_Id, OL.Last_Update_Date ORDER BY Order_Price_Attrib_Id DESC) AS rn
  FROM OE_Order_Lines_All OL
  LEFT JOIN OE_Order_Price_Attribs OPA
     ON OL.Header_Id = OPA.Header_Id
     AND OL.Line_Id = OPA.Line_Id
) AS S
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative suggestion to the accepted answer is to use a OUTER APPLY to fetch the one row only:

```sql
SELECT
    OL.*,
    OPA.*
FROM ONT.OE_Order_Lines_All OL
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM  ONT.OE_Order_Price_Attribs OPA
    WHERE OL.Header_Id = OPA.Header_Id
    AND OL.Line_Id = OPA.Line_Id
    ORDER BY Order_Price_Attrib_Id DESC
   ) OPA
```

In some cases it might be faster than materializing the whole thing and taking row_number on it.